# how to install tenda w311mi on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I a new ubuntu user.I recently installed ubuntu 14.04. How do I install tenda wireless usb wifi  adapter w311mi. Please help me.

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 1):

you have to search and install the following packages in ndiswrapper-utils, ndiswrapper-common and ndisgtk. try the steps given in following link below

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Tenda_W311M

(or)

http://alstevens.co.uk/how-to-install-wireless-usb-drivers-for-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

It should be plug and play with Ubuntu 14.04. The TP Link WN727n I have uses the same chipset rt5370 which runs off driver rt2800usb. https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Tenda_W311M    Wikidevi is full of information regarding Linux supported wireless devices, drivers, firmware ect...